# Why tomcat wont start with Failed to start apache tomcat web server tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203

Tags: java, apache, ubuntu, tomcat

**What i wanted to do**

I installed fresh linux **Ubuntu 16.04** to setup a test developing environment.

I wanted to **install**

1. **java** 8
2. **tomcat** 8

So i applied this tutorial and know that i dont have any previously java or
tomcat installed **before**.

[Tutorial for java 8 and tomcat 8](https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-1604/)
[Tutorial 2 same as the before with some more little hints](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04)

**What is the problem**

When i reached the step of **starting** tomcat , it failed.
*Failed to start apache tomcat web server tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203*.

[image: Failed to start apache tomcat web server tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**How i tried to reproduce:**

I followed the tutorial on a fresh **virtual box on ubuntu 16.04**.

And after i tried lot of the solution like the below:

1. Playing with chmod and permissions.
2. Un install and re install
3. Updating my ubuntu
4. Restarting my ubuntu
5. Reloading services
6. Double Quotation suggestions in .service paths in (**/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service**).
7. Commenting CATALINA_HOME line in .service file in (**/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service**).
8. Other googling solutions.

**Solution:**

From a very small comments from here ( [Thanks for the hint ))](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/installing-tomcat-8-on-a-centos-7-linux-vps/)  )
After i got the fail i ran

> You should run ‘`journalctl -xn`’ for more details about why Tomcat
>   failed to start. Thanks.

It gave me the main reason here is screen shot and notice in **RED**.

[image: Error with journalctl]

- **ALL PATHS WAS WRONG** ==> So i had to fix about five places for the **right path**... check Number **2** in **Orange** check image .

[image: check number 2 orange]

- **JAVA_HOME** **PATH** was **wrong** ==> so to change and find the correct one do this

[image: how to find java path]

Then change in **tomcat.service** 
check this image again this time look at **1** in bold yellow it should point to **JDK**.

[image: number two in orange]

**Result:**

So, apparently i had the path wrong , and it **WORKED**.

**Summary:**

When applying some tutorial keep an eye when you **extract** tomcat or etc..
because it may differ.

Answer (score 4):

alternatively you can just start tomcat by going to /path/to/tomcat/bin/ and running ./startup.sh

it will spit out all the variables it is using and you can configure your tomcat.service file accordingly.

Comment: Man you just saved my life! And why isn't it working when we run `systemctl start tomcat`?  Idk but your way worked, just go there by yourself and run the script!

Answer (score 0):

MY OS: POP!_OS (linux)

For me it was because i pointed JAVA_HOME to the wrong location. i pointed it to the binary folder but it should just be the home directory where you installed java. heres the turtorial that i followed

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7

it even helps you set up a tomcat user, although i changed just 3 variables. my entire systemd file is here

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.8.0_261 # i accidently had it /jre.../bin instead of just /jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
# the linked article had the entire thing in quotes?
# but only the value needs to be in quotes
Environment=CATALINA_OPTS='-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment=JAVA_OPTS='-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```